# How to bypass governor limits while fetching fields of Account object as there are more than 100 and the API breaks

Tags: apex, api, batch

There are more than 1000 fields in Account object and there is an API that returns all fields, given an object name. Call from the UI breaks since it's hitting the governor limits. Is there any better approach in handling this issue. We did think of batch API calls but would like to know how such cases are handled and if there are any better approaches.

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can share some code so that we can have look at it and provide suggestion for optimizing. AFAIK, the describe limit was removed for all API's [Descibe Limits Summer 14](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer14/New+Apex+Enhancements). You might be running into some other limit like CPU Time as describe calls are CPU time consuming. Is your code invoked through a trigger?

Comment: Honestly, 1000 fields on a given object in indicative of other issues.....How is it handled? A review of the business requirements and data model and a final plan to get the field count down.